# Excel macro select two ranges and compare

Tags: vba, excel, copy

This is a question that was asked to me in an interview. I have a excel list. It is copied to another location and then by mistake a row in the new location gets deleted.

Now I need to write a macro to compare the old and new ranges and then provide the missing data as result.

I can perhaps perform the comparison part. But the problem is I don't know how to get the selected range as input in a macro.

For eg. as soon as I select a range, it should be sent as input to the macro, then the macro should wait for another selection. As soon as I select the new range, the macro should compare and find the missing lines in new range.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: what was the interview for, out of interest?

Comment: @Cor_Blimey actually its data management profile that includes a lot of excel. Documentation and all....

Comment: @simoco : actually I tried using inputbox at first, but the requirement is that the range is selected with mouse and sent to macro for comparison. We don't have to manually enter row,column details.

Comment: there is no need to `to manually enter row,column`, when using `InputBox` with `Type:=8` range selects `with mouse` like this: `Set myRange = Application.InputBox(prompt := "Sample", type := 8)`

Comment: @simoco That worked pretty well, anyway to hide that InputBox? and send the input without pressing OK?..... thanks for your very helpful answer.

Comment: inputbox is really better as until the user presses OK you cannot be sure they have finished selecting their range. For example, often a user will click one cell (that would fire Selection change event) then shift clicks another to select a large range. You don't know which selection change event is the 'final' one. INputbox solves this by waiting until OK is clicked or Enter is pressed. I think doing anything else would result in a poorer quality product. Showing a box is a good thing ;)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the selection per mouse click you could look at [the link I sent in the comments of the other answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220977%28v=office.11%29.aspx). Selection_Change is an event which gets triggered when you change the selection of a worksheet (not only mouseclick but move-by-keys as well). The target coming in is the cell which you have selected. You can pass this as a range on to a function.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        showMsg Target
    End Sub

    Private Function showMsg(r As Range)
        MsgBox r.Address
    End Function
```

You can just as well use another event like BeforeDoubleClick or BeforeRightClick. Check out the events of Excel and choose the one you feel fits best.

If you only want the function to be triggered for a certain range you can filter it.

`If target.column <> 1 then exit function`

If you don't want the event to trigger your function each time you change a selection you can choose one cell to be the switch which gets triggered by the same event.

`If target.address = "$A$1" Then Call toggleSearch()`

with toggleSearch being the switching function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical diff (and a simple one at that), you shouldn't select by hand or anything. Just sort the two lists in an identical way, then run a Sub which loops over the number of rows in the source sheet comparing each row with the same row in the target sheet. The first mismatch you get is the missing line.

This example assumes both sheets are in the same workbook but you can easily adapt it

```
Public Sub diffThem()

    Dim src as Worksheet, trg as Worksheet
    Dim r as Range, i as Integer
    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source")
    Set trg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Destination")

    Set r = src.Range("A1")
    For i = 1 to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source").UsedRange.Rows.Count

        If r.EntireRow <> trg.Range("A" & r.Row).EntireRow Then 
            MsgBox("The missing row is " & r.Row)
            Exit Sub
        End if

    Set r = r.Offset(1,0)
    Next i

End Sub
```

If EntireRow cannot be run due to different layouts or whatever then loop the columns at that point.

Comment: Btw: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220977%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: That can actually help in comparisons and hence I'll would have given you +1 for this, but the arrow says am not reputed enough. :3

Still, the problem remains a bit unsolved, I want the selected range, which may be anywhere in the sheet (not particularly at A1) to be selected by mouse and sent to macro for comparison. 

Your answer really helped, and I will really appreciate further if you could tell me anyway to send selected range as input, without manually entering the details in any inputbox etc.